# python lambda map over nested list

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, lambda, nested-lists

I recently received the following question in a Hackerrank that I wasn't able to answer and I haven't found the correct answer anywhere else.

Complete the lambda map function:
given a array such as [[1,2,3,-1,2],[2,4,-3]] take the square of all the non-negative numbers in the two arrays. The output is suppose to be:

```
[1,4,9,4]

[4,16]
```

Additionally, the array will also contain an additional number at the beginning of the array which is the length of the array. So in the above example, the length is 2 so the final array that will be passed through the function will be [2, [1,2,3,-1,2],[2,4,-3]]. (We don't want to take the square of the initial number, in this case 2)

```
def lambdamap(arr):

    final = map(

 #write your lambda function here

 , arr)
    
return final
```

create a lambda function within the map that creates the desired output.

I have tried a number of different ways such as

```
map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x>0, arr))
```

But this does not work on nested lists like the array that is passed through the function.
Please let me know if there is any information I can provide to help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not certain of this, it sounds like the input might have the length included in the beginning and it needs to be passed through untouched.   If that's the case, here's a single lambda function that will take the input and produce the desired output:

```
lambda i: [n**2 for n in i if n > 0] if isinstance(i, list) else i
```

This portion does the squaring on the non-negatives:  `[n**2 for n in i if n > 0]`

But only if the value is a list:  `if isinstance(i, list)`

Otherwise pass the value through:  `else i`

That means this input `[2, [1, 2, 3, -1, 2], [2, 4, -3]]` returns this output `[2, [1, 4, 9, 4], [4, 16]]`

Comment: Weren't we barred from using list comprehension? OP (@Carl_christian) was very adamant about this. Also the output here does not match the output shape specified by the OP. I'm baffled...

Comment: OP clarifies that the input to the function is `[2, [1,2,3,-1,2],[2,4,-3]]`.  The example function uses `map` and the requirements are that a lambda function has to be called on each element of the input list.  This means `2`, `[1,2,3,-1,2]` and `[2,4,-3]` all need to be evaluated independently by the same lambda function.  The wording was unclear to me, but it sounded like the `2` should be passed through untouched.  As far as list comprehension, it didn't look like there was any stipulation as to what was inside the lambda function.

Comment: Right. I agree that the question is not clear on that. But in the comments he said so. Anyways...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a lambda function within a lambda function. The result isn't that pretty, but it works:

```py
list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y ** 2, filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))), arr[1:]))
```

With the given input case, this outputs:

```py
[[1, 4, 9, 4], [4, 16]]
```

If you can't use list slicing, you could use `filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), arr)` rather than `arr[1:]`.

---

Let's start at the innermost lambda functions and work our way outwards. To simplify things, we start by considering how to perform this operation on a single list, called `x`:

- `filter(lambda z: z > 0, x)` gives us all the positive elements in `x`.
- We then square all of these elements using `map`: `map(lambda y: y ** 2, ...)`
- This gives us `map(lambda y: y ** 2, filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))`.

This gives us something that works for a single list. How do we extend it to work with a list of lists? Well, the operation is defined in the same way for each list, so use `map` again! (slicing off the first element because it isn't a list, and transforming the map objects into lists to match the desired output).

This finally gives us:

```py
list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y ** 2, filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))), arr[1:]))
```

as specified originally.

Answer (score -1):

```
def lambdamap(arr):
    return map(
        lambda x: map(
            lambda y: y**2,
            filter(lambda z: z > 0, x)
        ),
        map(
            lambda b: b[1],
            filter(lambda a: a[0] > 0, enumerate(lst))
        )
    )
```

For better readability we can also do:

```
def lambdamap(arr):
    _arr = map(
        lambda b: b[1],
        filter(lambda a: a[0] > 0, enumerate(lst))
    )

    return map(
        lambda x: map(lambda y: y**2, filter(lambda z: z > 0, x)),
        _arr
    )
```

**Outcome**

```
lst = [2, [1, 2, 3, -1, 2], [2, 4, -3]]


outcome = [list(x) for x in list(lambdamap(lst))]
print(outcome)
```

Obviously, the list comprehension here is just to see the outcome printed out as a list. If the outcome needs to actually be a list, we can wrap the first two `map()` functions in a `list()` function inside `lambdamap()`

Comment: You didn't read the question

Comment: It sadly had to be completed as a lambda map function. I thought the list comprehension was much more straightforward as well

Comment: See the updated answer. That was thought process! And now we can replace the inner list comprehension too

Comment: You still haven't read the entire question. The only thing you are allowed to write is the `lambda` not modifications to the array (i.e. `arr[1:]`)

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I am thinking and trying to help here. Thanks for your comments though

Comment: @re-za I really appreciate your help on this.  I sadly don't think I am allowed to modify the array as Ryan Schaefer pointed out but this is still really helpful!

Comment: @Carl_christian see updated answer. I'll see if I can remove the `arr[1:]` but the process seems to work

Comment: @Carl_christian what else expect for `lambda` and `map` can we use? Already it seems `filter` is ok. What else? Is `enumerate` ok?

Comment: @re-za I believe enumerate is allowed as well.

Comment: @Carl_christian so the updated code is allowed?